# Jquery jcrop cropper frame in not aligned properly from bottom

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I'm using jquery jcrop for cropping images. Everything is working perfectly except the cropper frame is not aligned properly from bottom. As you can see:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XZk9.png)

It feels quite disturbing while using the tool. I've tried to play with css but did not get any success. Any suggestions to sort this problem out?

CSS Code:

```
.jcrop-holder {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius:20px;
}
/* Selection Border */
.jcrop-vline,
.jcrop-hline {
  background: #ffffff url(../graphics/crop.gif);
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.jcrop-vline {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px !important;
}
.jcrop-vline.right {
  right: 0;
}
.jcrop-hline {
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.jcrop-hline.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Invisible click targets */
.jcrop-tracker {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* "turn off" link highlight */
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* disable callout, image save panel */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* disable cut copy paste */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
/* Selection Handles */
.jcrop-handle {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 1px #eeeeee solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  font-size: 1px;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-n {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-s {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-e {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-w {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 50%;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-nw {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-ne {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-se {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  right: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-sw {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
/* Dragbars */
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-n,
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-s {
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-e,
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-w {
  height: 100%;
  width: 7px;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-n {
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-s {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-e {
  margin-right: -4px;
  right: 0;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-w {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
/* The "jcrop-light" class/extension */
.jcrop-light .jcrop-vline,
.jcrop-light .jcrop-hline {
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70) !important;
  opacity: .70!important;
}
.jcrop-light .jcrop-handle {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* The "jcrop-dark" class/extension */
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-vline,
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-hline {
  background: #000000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70) !important;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-handle {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* Simple macro to turn off the antlines */
.solid-line .jcrop-vline,
.solid-line .jcrop-hline {
  background: #ffffff;
}
/* Fix for twitter bootstrap et al. */
.jcrop-holder img,
img.jcrop-preview {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Please [share your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Updated the question